# Use different flask object handle request in one appengine service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, app.yaml

For some reason I intend to handle request with more than one flask request handler in a GAE service, and use different url prefix to determine which handler should handler the request.

For example:

I have handler one in file A.py:

```
import Flask, ......

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return "Hello this is app A"
```

and file B.py for second handler B.py

```
import Flask, ......

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello this is app B"
```

and in the app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
......
handlers:
- url: /app_a/.*
script: A.app

-url: /app_b/.*
script: B.app
```

when I run the code locally, both my http://localhost:8080/app_a/
and http://localhost:8080/app_b/ 
return not found, 404 result.

Can any one tell me what's the problem I encounter? or where I should fix to make my code right?

Comment: Have you tried running the 2 different flask applications on different ports, by adding a 'host=(xxx.x.x.x.x)' line in your app.run() statement

Comment: But my goal is trying to access two different flask application on same port but different route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correct path in decorator because AppEngine would pass the whole path. So it should be something like:

```
@app.route("/app_a/")
def hello():
  return "Hello this is app A"
```